# How to activate when i click outside the program on screen minimized the program

Tags: windows

How can I activate the option that allows me when I click outside the program like clicking on desktop outside chrome minimized chrome because it's not active on my windows and when i click outside the programs it doesn't minimized it

Comment: Please don't just repost an exact copy/paste of a question already closed as "needs more detail". Please provide some actual detail. It's really not easy to tell what it is you actually need. Re: https://superuser.com/questions/1812601/how-to-activate-when-i-click-outside-the-program-on-screen-minimized-the-program If you're struggling to explain it in English, then use your own language & [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com) to make your request clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not natively support this.

But I've wanted something similar myself and went looking for a way.

I came across a product called Actual Tools Window Manager, and it allows you to automatically minimize any window after you click outside of it or switching to any other window, not just the desktop.
[image]
You can put a delay on it too, and this program can do so much more.

Its not free though, but its worth its money, and for the duration of your license, you can update to a newer version. If your license runs out, you can continue to use the program forever, just not upgrade to a newer version.

If you really only want the minimizing functions, you can get their ActualTools Window Minimizer, which also features this functionality, just not all the other cool stuff. See here: https://www.actualtools.com/windowminimizer/

Download the demo version and try it out for 14 days and see if this really is what you want.

I used this for quite a while, but eventually I stopped using it. I now use TidyTabs which allows me to group all programs together using a tabbed interface. If I minimize one program in this tab group, they all minimize. If I switch to another program, only that program is visible. They all share the same size too.

I mention this alternative because I found the automatic minimize great at first, until I wanted to do multitasking. Having 2 windows open next to eachother was a pain. I had to setup exclusion rules. For example, I do web development. Having an editor open and a webbrowser won't work if you click the editor, and then your browser minimizes.

For that reason, download the demo of either ActualTools Window Manger or their Window Minimizer and try it out for 14 days. If its really what you want, consider buying it. I bought it, and I love their Window Manager (I had the Transparent Windows first, and later bought the whole suite). I don't use everything of it, but I do use most of it.

Comment: it doesn't work for me the first program i installed it and still i can't minimized any program to show disktop

Comment: It does not activate out of the box. You have to specifically tell this to the ActualTools program. Either use the Default Settings to apply it to everything, or create a custom rule per program and apply it to that. ActualTools has a systemtray icon. Right-click it, Show log window, and you will be able to see how it detected your changes. Also do note that it comes with a few program settings too, which may trigger and not let the default settings activate. Toy around with it and make something work, so you at least know how the program works.

Comment: How to not minimized when click on task bar just minimize the window when click outside it like click on disktop or another program but when i click on taskbar or voluem for audio as examble it minmimized the window i don't need that

Comment: The only option you have is to minimize when the program no longer is active (lost focus). That is what you can set. Clicking on the taskbar also makes the program lose focus. If that is not desired, then you've run out of luck. Windows does not support it natively. If you are okay in pressing a keyboard shortcut, WIN+M and WIN+D will minimize all and show the desktop. Or use my TidyTabs alternative. You minimize a window by minimizing it, and it behaves for all. Only thing is, clicking the desktop will not minimize the window.

Comment: How to use tidytabs to minimized the tab?

Comment: TidyTabs only combines all programs into one. Minimize your active program, and they all minimize. Make sure that you drag the tabs of all programs into eachother so they form a strip of tabs. You can use the settings to automatically group programs together.

Comment: so there are no any program to do minimize the application when you right-click outside of it, rather than bringing other applications in front of it ? rather than actual tool minmizer ?

Comment: For windows, not to my knowledge. Maybe there are, but that turns this into a software recommendation, which is offtopic for SuperUser.